# when clicked navbar, how to switch partial view in other view

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have 4 Views(index view, navigation bar view, Partial view1, partialview2) in One controller
I'd like to switch The Partial View in index view when click navbaritem.

I set LeftPanelPartial in @section.

If I click navbar item, switch ProdFViewPartial() to ProdJViewPartial()

How Can I Get This.

check my code

Controller

```
namespace DXWMes.Controllers
{
    public class ProdController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Prod
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ProdRepository ProdRepo = new ProdRepository();
            return View(ProdRepo.GetProdFData("1", "F11", "20220901"));
        }
        public ActionResult ProdFViewPartial()
        {
            ProdRepository ProdRepo = new ProdRepository();
            return PartialView("ProdFViewPartial",ProdRepo.GetProdFData("1", "F11", "20220901"));
        }

        public ActionResult ProdJViewPartial()
        {
            ProdRepository ProdRepo = new ProdRepository();
            return View("ProdJViewPartial", ProdRepo.GetProdJData("1", "20220901"));
        }
```

VIEW - Index

```
@model List<DXWMes.Model.ProdFModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Prod";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Head {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ProdView.css")" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/ProdView.js")"></script>
}


@section LeftPanelContent {
    @Html.Partial("LeftPanelPartial")
}

@section RightPanelContent {
    <div class="settings-content">
        <h2>Settings</h2>
        <p>Place your content here</p>
    </div>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.Partial("ProdFViewPartial")
}
<div id="detailView"> </div>
```

View - LeftPanelPartial

```
<h3 class="leftpanel-section section-caption">Production</h3>
@Html.DevExpress().NavBar(navBarSettings =>
{
    navBarSettings.Name = "NavBar";
    navBarSettings.AllowSelectItem = true;
    navBarSettings.ShowGroupHeaders = false;
    navBarSettings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    navBarSettings.ControlStyle.CssClass = "ProdNavbar";
    navBarSettings.Styles.Item.CssClass = "item";
    navBarSettings.Groups.Add(group =>
    {
        group.Items.Add(item =>
        {
            item.Name = "ProdE1";
            item.Selected = true;
        });
        group.Items.Add(item =>
        {
            item.Name = "ProdE5";
        });
        group.Items.Add(item =>
        {
            item.Name = "ProdF";
        });
        group.Items.Add(item =>
        {
            item.Name = "ProdJ";
        });
    });
    navBarSettings.ClientSideEvents.ItemClick = "onProdNavBarItemClick";
}).GetHtml()
```

JS

```
(function () {
    var selectedIds;
    var itemids;

    function onProdInit(s, e) {
        AddAdjustmentDelegate(adjustProd);
        updateToolbarButtonsState();
    }
    function onProdSelectionChanged(s, e) {
        updateToolbarButtonsState();
    }
    function adjustProd() {
        Prod.AdjustControl();
    }
    function updateToolbarButtonsState() {
        var enabled = Prod.GetSelectedRowCount() > 0;
        pageToolbar.GetItemByName("Export").SetEnabled(enabled);
    }

    function onProdNavBarItemClick(s, e)
    {
        $.ajax({
            Url: ' @Url.Action(e.item.name, "Prod")',
            type: 'GET',
        }).done(funtion(result) {
            if(result.redirectTo)
        $('#detailView').html(result);
        }).fail(function (jqXHR, exception) {
        showError(jqXHR);
    })
    //switch (e.item.name) {
    //    case "ProdJ"
```